# Batch processing tif images? Converting .tif to .jpeg

Tags: image-processing, convert, batch

I'm trying to mass convert a handful of `.tif` files. I found phatch could look like a good candidiate but I'm running Ubuntu 11.04. Looks like they don't have a `.deb` for my version.

Anyone have any alternatives to phatch or any other recommendations as to quickly batch convert `tif` to `jpeg` files.

I'm looking for a non-Photoshop (ala Wine) solution.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Easy. Install **imagemagick**:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Its simplest usage is:

```
convert File.tif File.jpg
```

It is smart and goes by your file extension.

Now, for doing batch conversions, we shall use a loop.

`cd` into the directory where your tif files are.

then:

```
for f in *.tif; do  echo "Converting $f"; convert "$f"  "$(basename "$f" .tif).jpg"; done
```

Read also as:

```
for f in *.tif
do  
    echo "Converting $f" 
    convert "$f"  "$(basename "$f" .tif).jpg" 
done
```

That should do it!

Also, once you convert all of the files and verify the new jpg's integrity, just run `rm *.tif` in that directory to delete all your old .tif files.  Be careful with asterisks though, don't add a space after the `*`, or you will delete all your files in the directory.

Tip: If you have a folder with subfolders that holds these images. You could use this for loop to find all .TIF files within that folder:

```
for f in $(find -name *.tif); do ...; done
```

Comment: Is this supposed to print `Converting filename.tif` or `Converting filename`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate it will say "Converting filename.tif".  the `basename` command takes 2 arguments, for example `basename file.tif .tif` will return "file" stripping the .tif extension away.  You could modify the loop to say "Converting filename.tif to filename.jpg" with the same basename command, if you wished.

Comment: `find`'s first arg shoud be the path, so that last line should be `for f in $(find . -name *.tif); do ...; done` (since we `cd`ed in the directory before). I tried editing @Matt's answer but edits must be at least 6 chars for some reason.

Comment: I get this warning when I run that snippet:

> convert-im6.q16: Wrong data type 3 for "GainControl"; tag ignored. `TIFFReadCustomDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/985.

Answer (score 31):

I found this question while trying to do it myself; for future reference you can also do it like this:

```
convert *.tiff -set filename: "%t" %[filename:].jpg
```

or to put it in a subdirectory

```
mkdir jpg
convert *.tiff -set filename: "%t" jpg/%[filename:].jpg
```

Comment: Yay for built-in filename handling.

Comment: This worked great for me with png files as well. The behavior for pdf's was different, however.

Comment: I would love to see this working, however, this reported a Bus Error on ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16 (OpenMP) on Ubuntu 64. The accepted answer works fine.

Comment: A word of warning: This froze for me the entire system (GNOME 3) and I had to hard shut down the computer

Comment: For a large number of files, this runs into memory issues. I split mine into few batches to use this.

Answer (score 5):

Use `mogrify`, the tool intended for batch processing inside `ImageMagick`

```
mogrify -format jpg *.tif
```

In case you don't have `ImageMagick`:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to @Matt's answer that if you would like the files to be saved in the subfolders you can do the following:

```
find . -iname *.tif | while read f; do echo "Converting ${f}"; convert "${f}" "${f%.*}.jpg"; done
```

This also handles the issue if your file-path/name has spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) should be able to convert them. It is a package of commandline programs, if you are OK with that.

Part of that is **convert** -

man convert:

> convert  -  convert  between  image formats as well as resize an image,
>          blur, crop, despeckle, dither, draw on, flip, join, re-sample, and much
>          more.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a GUI application, you can install Phatch through the normal repositories. Just open **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for it. I'm not on 11.04 anymore but I had it installed back then.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above use `*.tif` for tif selection, but this will return an error if you have too many files in your current working directory. A simple workaround is to use a python script to convert each file in the cwd:

```py
import glob, os

for c, i in enumerate(glob.glob('ecco_images/*')):
  print(' * converting', i)
  os.system('convert ' + i + ' ' + i.replace('.TIF','.jpg'))
```

Comment: `for f in *.tif` won't error out, but `convert *.tif` will.

Comment: Ah, thanks @muru! I thought the * expansion would be the same at the os level, but am happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

### The GIMP GUI Solution Using a Batch Process Plugin

#### Works in Ubuntu 18.04 using GIMP 2.8

Batch Processor Input dialog window

[image: David's Batch Processor input dialog window]

Batch Processor output dialog window

[image: Batch Processor Output Dialog Window]

#### Installation Instructions

1. Download the current plugin file from [DBP - David's Batch Processor](http://members.ozemail.com.au/%7Ehodsond/dbp.html) homepage to your desktop.  For Ubuntu 18.04 running Gimp 2. 8 the file that worked for me was
   [dbpSrc-1-1-9.tgz](http://www.ozemail.com.au/%7Ehodsond/dbpSrc-1-1-9.tgz).
2. Grab some GIMP development files:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev gcc cpp g++
   ```
3. Switch to the system source code directory:

   ```
   cd /usr/src/
   ```
4. Extract the plugin from your Desktop to its own source code directory.  Replace `[username]` with your current username, and use the filename that you downloaded above in step 1:

   ```
   sudo tar -xvzf /home/[username]/Desktop/dbpSrc-1-1-9.tgz
   ```
5. Change to the plugin's source code directory:

   ```
   cd dbp-1.1.9
   ```
6. Compile the plugin:

   ```
   make
   ```
7. Install the plugin:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
8. Start GIMP and you will find the plugin under **Menu > Filters > Batch Process**

   [image: GIMP Batch Process.. Menu Path]