# Batch Convert Images from One Format to Another while maintaining directory structure, and removing originals

Tags: image-processing

I've looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg), and while it works there a few issues:

1. All converted images are placed in the directory from which the command is called.
2. The original images are kept.

I need to convert around 70,000 .tif and .jpgs to .pngs.  It's really important the the files when converted are placed in their normal directories.

I can do a batch rm of .tff/.jpg's at the end if that's the best way to handle removing the old files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in $(find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f) ;
    do
    convert $f $(dirname $f)/$(basename -s .jpg $f).png ;
    done
```

- `find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f` : search for file ending with ".jpg" case insensitive
- `$(dirname $f)` : relative path to the folder containing file $f
- `$(basename -s .jpg $f)` : filename without the suffix ".jpg"

In old Ubuntu basename may need to be run with different way:

```
basename $f .jpg
```

Convert is a part of imagemagick (As reference see [Batch Processing tif images: Converting .tif to .jpeg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg))  , to install

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: Thanks, I get:

basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.


A lot of times...

Comment: @user2757729 `basename` has a `-s` option in Ubuntu. Are you sure you are on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yea I'm definitely on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Comment: Just did Man basename, don't see -s as a flag... Don't see any flags listed though.

Comment: Try with `basename --suffix=.jpg $f` or `basename $f .jpg`

Comment: basename --suffix=.jpg had a similar issue, except the flag was on '-'.  Basename $f isn't printing anything... not sure if that means it's working or not.

Comment: looks like basename $f .jpg was the way to go

Comment: The `find -iname` finds `foo.JPG` too - but the `basename $f .jpg` does not handle that.

Comment: Does not work on file names with spaces

Comment: "${f%.*}.png" works and @user2757729 wants to remove the originals

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for file names with spaces also.

To remove originals:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f); do
    convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"; rm "$f"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

To keep originals: remove the < ; rm "$f" > part

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f); do
    convert "$f" "${f%.*}.png"
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Since @user2757729 wanted to remove the originals