# Script to write all filenames inside a folder and its subfolders to a csv file

Tags: command-line

I would like to write a shell script in order to write all files ending with .tif in  a given directory and all its subdirectories to a csv file.

The directory contains various sub-directories and those can also contain .zip folders so the script should be able to extract the names from zip folders too.

I first thought about separating these steps though (unzipping and getting the filenames) but I'm not sure if this is really necessary.

Since I'm really new to working with the Shell, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How to loop through sub folders? http://askubuntu.com/questions/406462/batch-convert-images-from-one-format-to-another-while-maintaining-directory-stru/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To search for `.tif` files inside a folder and its subfolders, then write the output in a `.csv` file you can use the following command:

```bsh
find /path/to/folder -iname '*.tif' -type f >tif_filenames.csv
```

To search also inside `.zip` files and *append* the output to the previous `tif_filenames.csv` file you can use:

```bsh
find /path/to/folder -iname '*.zip' -type f -exec unzip -l '{}' \; | process
```

where `process` is the following bash function:

```bsh
function process() {
  while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^Archive:\s*(.*) ]] ; then
      ar="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ \s*([^ ]*\.tif)$ ]] ; then
      echo "${ar}: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
  done
}
```

<sup>Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12048/37944</sup>

Comment: I think it will be `*.tif` instead of `*.sh`. Isn't it?

Comment: @souravc Yes, you have right. I tested those commands for `.sh` files.

Comment: me too. That is why I noticed it. One more thing in the first case your output will consist the path with its name.

Comment: @souravc Yep, this was my intention. The OP didn't didn't specified clear this and for me is better to see the full path for files.

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked for me. another way to retrieve names inside zip files is: unzip -l mypath/myfile.zip | awk '{print $NF}' >> echo /home/myname/mylist.csv

Comment: Hey, would you know how to modify the first one liner to have it only keep the filnames (disregard the paths)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given below,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find . -iname "*.tif" -type f)
do
    echo "$(basename $f)"
done

for f in $(find . -iname "*.zip" -type f)
do
    less $f | grep "tif" | awk '{print $NF}'
done
```

Save the file say as `find_tif.sh` in the directory where all the `tif` files and sub directories are located. give it executable permission.

```
chmod +x find_tif.sh
```

**Useage**

```
./find_tif.sh >> tif_name_file.csv
```