# How to convert png to tiff?

Tags: 14.04, convert, png

i need to convert png files to tiff. Is there an easy way to do so in Ubuntu 14.04?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried GIMP? It's a little tricky to use, but a good program for image editing and converting.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg commandline command is "convert"

Comment: You don't need to use batch, but rather [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/).

Answer (score 20):

Install `imagemagick`:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

An a simple command:

```
convert <your_png> out.tiff
```

Or for all files in your folder:

```
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" "${f%%.*}.tiff"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `convert`:

```
convert blah.png blah.tiff
```

If you don't have it, try:

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Installing graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat worked!